# Create Dictionary of Specific Keys and Values from a Lst of Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which looks like this:

```
dic = [
 {'id': 'Team1', 'name': 'Team One', 'description': 'This is team 1', 'type': 'team'},
 {'id': 'Team2', 'name': 'Team Two', 'description': 'This is team 2', 'type': 'team'}, 
 {'id': 'Team3', 'name': 'Team Three', 'description': 'This is team 3', 'type': 'team'}
]
```

I want to create a dictionary of all the `id` values and `name` values so the output will look like this:

```
{'Team1': 'Team One', 'Team2': 'Team Two', 'Team3': 'Team Three'}
```

What is the best pythonic way of achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict comprehension:

```py
dcts = [ {'id': 'Team1', 'name': 'Team One', 'description': 'This is team 1', 'type': 'team'}, {'id': 'Team2', 'name': 'Team Two', 'description': 'This is team 2', 'type': 'team'}, {'id': 'Team3', 'name': 'Team Three', 'description': 'This is team 3', 'type': 'team'} ]

output = {dct['id']: dct['name'] for dct in dcts}
print(output) # {'Team1': 'Team One', 'Team2': 'Team Two', 'Team3': 'Team Three'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

out = dict(map(itemgetter('id', 'name'), dic))
```

output: `{'Team1': 'Team One', 'Team2': 'Team Two', 'Team3': 'Team Three'}`

used input:

```
dic = [{'id': 'Team1', 'name': 'Team One', 'description': 'This is team 1', 'type': 'team'},
       {'id': 'Team2', 'name': 'Team Two', 'description': 'This is team 2', 'type': 'team'},
       {'id': 'Team3', 'name': 'Team Three', 'description': 'This is team 3', 'type': 'team'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictt = [ {'id': 'Team1', 'name': 'Team One', 'description': 'This is team 1', 'type': 'team'}, {'id': 'Team2', 'name': 'Team Two', 'description': 'This is team 2', 'type': 'team'}, {'id': 'Team3', 'name': 'Team Three', 'description': 'This is team 3', 'type': 'team'} ]    
new={}
for a in dictt:
    new[a['id']]=a['name']
print (new)
#{'Team1': 'Team One', 'Team2': 'Team Two', 'Team3': 'Team Three'}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).